# sympy Exp of Square Matrix gives Index error

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra, sympy

```
g, mu, m, n = symbols('g mu m n')


mat = Matrix([[g, - I*mu*sqrt(m+1),I*mu*sqrt(n+1),0],
              [-I*mu*sqrt(m+1),g/2,0,I*mu*sqrt(n+1)],
              [I*mu*sqrt(n+1),0,g/2, -I*mu* sqrt(m+1)],
              [0,I*mu*sqrt(n+1),-I*mu*sqrt(m+1),g/2]])

t = symbols('t')

(-mat*t).exp()
```

The matrix is `4x4` and the elements are symbolic. It should work since it's a rather simplified matrix. 
The above  gives  the follow error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-eab894638457> in <module>
      1 start_time = timeit.default_timer()
      2 
----> 3 (-mat*t).exp()
      4 
      5 elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py in exp(self)
   2830                 "Exponentiation is valid only for square matrices")
   2831         try:
-> 2832             P, J = self.jordan_form()
   2833             cells = J.get_diag_blocks()
   2834         except MatrixError:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py in jordan_form(self, calc_transform, **kwargs)
   1612             if not calc_transform:
   1613                 return restore_floats(jordan_mat)
-> 1614             jordan_basis = [eig_mat(eig, 1).nullspace()[0] for eig in blocks]
   1615             basis_mat = mat.hstack(*jordan_basis)
   1616             return restore_floats(basis_mat, jordan_mat)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1612             if not calc_transform:
   1613                 return restore_floats(jordan_mat)
-> 1614             jordan_basis = [eig_mat(eig, 1).nullspace()[0] for eig in blocks]
   1615             basis_mat = mat.hstack(*jordan_basis)
   1616             return restore_floats(basis_mat, jordan_mat)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Really no clue why this happens. And it goes SUPER slow while on Mathematica takes ~minutes to complete

Comment: That looks like a 4x4 matrix to me. Is it the one that you intended to show?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Yeap, you can test it on a notebook or something (although it takes ages). It gives that error even though it is Square

Comment: I think this is just a bug which should be reported in github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: So no way around it?

Comment: ..well...to get the `exp` you need the diagonalization. This is a forth order polynomial to solve for the eigenvalues. Then getting the eigenvectors. Just looking at `sympy`s output for a simplified `3x3` shows that there is plenty of computation involved. I guess the guys from Wolfram spend quite some time to optimize this.

Comment: @mikuszefski I'm fine with it taking its time. The error I can't understand

Comment: Sure. You matrix is of type `Matrix([[g, a, b, 0], [a, c, 0, b], [b, 0, c, a], [0, b, a, c]])`. If `c=g`. it works relatively fast. I guess the comment above, that this probably a bug in the Jordan decomposition , seems reasonable.